# Is there a way to select all the objects inside a collection?

Tags: selection-tools, collections, outliner, select

Is there a way to select all the objects inside collection using shortcut?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are in the 3D View, select one of the collection objects and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Collection*. In the *Outliner*, right click on the collection name > *Select Objects*.

Comment: Thanx! I upgrade this methode, by add a shortcut to select all the griup (collection) by just double click on any object from group! see screenshot

https://yadi.sk/i/JiVM4yY9Z3HBwg

Comment: wow interesting

Comment: You can also RIGHTCLICK the collection in the collections panel and choose "select all objects in hierarchy".

Comment: @Piton812 In Blenders Keymap preferences, under which section did you add this new keyboard shortcut?

Comment: 3dView-3dView(Global)-Object Mode - Select Grouped

Comment: Can anyone explain why the "right-click the collection in the Outliner" option never seems to select anything in 2.92? If memory serves, it didn't do so in previous versions either.

Comment: it works fine with my 2.92, so I don't know what happens for you

Comment: As I now see, it works for me as well if I open a new file. So something might be wrong with the old file I was working in.