# Selecting Collections

Tags: groups, collections

In the older versions of blender, you could group objects and they would be treated like one object.
In blender 2.8, groups have been replaced with collections. The collections are not treated as one object. How do you select a collection like you would a group?

Comment: I guess what you want is Shift A > Collection instance. It's the same as dupli-group in 2.7x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hi! Is there the way to select all the objects inside collection using shortcut (Blender 2.8)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148444/hi-is-there-the-way-to-select-all-the-objects-inside-collection-using-shortcut)